# Is it ever appropriate to catch Exception if you want to your application to continue running

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I know there are a lot of questions dealing with catching `Exception` generically, but from what I've been able to find, the general consensus seems to be never catch something unless you know what to do with it, and the only time you catch it all is if you are logging an error and then immediately shutting down your application.

Sometimes, though, I feel lazy, and just want to handle all the exceptions instead of figuring out all the possible exceptions that could be thrown and inevitably missing one and months later needing to put in a hotfix to catch another exception that I didn't originally expect. Below is an example

```cs
foreach(file in someListOfFiles)
{
    try
    {
        doSomethingWithThisFile(file);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logWhyTheFileFailed(file, e);
    }
}
```

The main question is, what are some practical examples of bad exceptions that could be caught here that really shouldn't be caught and could cause some major problems for an application (more major than just fumbling around for a bit and ultimately crashing somewhere else because things are truly unstable)?

In this example, I don't really care why the processing of the file failed, I just want to log it and move on with trying to process the remaining files. This is especially important for long running processes where it's important to process as much as you can and then if there are failures you can try to address them after everything has been processed rather than stopping 10 files in out of 1000 just because there was some weird failure.

The concern with catching everything seems to be the general concern of "what if you catch something that shouldn't be caught and how will you know things are stable enough for your application to really continue?"

I'm trying to figure out what specific scenarios would that actually be? Some common ones that people throw out are things like `OutOfMemoryException` or `StackOverflowException`, but `StackOverflowException` can't be caught since .net 2.0, and `OutOfMemoryException` doesn't mean your memory is somehow corrupted or that you are literally out of all memory and drive space, so it seems reasonable to continue even after an exception like that because as long as you aren't using any data from that file it shouldn't be affecting the rest of your code.

Even if an exception was thrown because things aren't stable for whatever reason, if I continue in this case I'm trying to think of what kind of damage could be caused if I tried to continue and it ultimately crashed and died somewhere else because things were so unstable.

Obviously this is a very simplified case, and it's not just `IOException` that needs to be caught. Maybe you are compressing or decompressing and there is some kind of corruption, maybe it's a formatting error, maybe it's too large or too small, so maybe it's a `FormatException`, `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, `SomeThirdPartyLibraryCustomException`, `UnauthorizedAccessException` etc.

Comment: My first question would be why `doSomethingWithThisFile` isn't catching any non-fatal exceptions itself, and returning a normal bool "false" response or error code?  If something truly unexpected is happening while it runs, is it really safe to continue?  If the caller has no idea why it triggered an exception, closing the program seems safest here.  I suppose there might be some case for frozen legacy code where you can't fix it because (reasons)?

Comment: Also, for this example if  `doSomethingWithThisFile(file);` was some erratic black box legacy code prone to crashing, it might be better to wrap it in a bit of code and run it as a separate process?

Comment: In this example, `doSomethingWithThisFile(file)` is just a private method and it's code that I have in my control, but ultimately it's the same question. If I'm catching all the non-fatal exceptions in `doSomethingWithThisFile(file)` and I forget a non-fatal exception, then instead of returning true or false I would be throwing an exception, and I'm back to making a hotfix and adding the exception that I missed in my original analysis.

Comment: The specific scenario that inspired this question is processing a lot of files, but files can get corrupted and depending on how you are processing the file it can throw different exceptions depending on how it was corrupted. From the top level application I don't really care that it's corrupted I just want to know that I need to ignore that file and use as much data that is not corrupted.

Comment: How confident are you that there aren't any problems with resource leaks or damage to global state the private method can access even unintentionally?  It's C# not C++ so less dangerous in general, but if the exception could be anything can you predict the effects of possibly multiple of them?  If the function is in a separate applet you can let it crash and let the OS clean up after it.  It feels like a judgment call with no absolute rule.  It's probably best to exit in general, but if you know what the code  could do when it goes horribly wrong then just logging and continuing might be fine.

Answer (score -1):

**[1]** The good practice is to avoid exceptions when feasible, for example :

- use `success = int.TryParse(str, out number)` rather than `try { number = int.Parse(str) } catch {success=false }`.
- instead of processing a FormatException in Convert.FromBase64String, use TryFromBase64String.

**[2]** In some cases, you cannot avoid exceptions :

- For example, if a filename is provided in a textbox, an exception may occur if file doesn't exists when you read it. You have then to process the error, displaying an error message to the user.

When using such functions, I usually encapsulate them in a small dedicated function that catches exceptions and returns success or failure.

**[3]** Finally, you may receive unexpected exceptions because there is a bug in your code. I suggest either to let the system display the problem and the stack trace what helps to identify the problem. In some particular cases, you will need to catch exceptions at the higher level so as to log the problem.

Comment: Downvoted because this does not address the question. Also, displaying the actual exception message and/or stack trace harms your security posture ([link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/is-it-a-vulnerability-to-display-exception-messages-in-an-error-page))

Comment: @JohnWu : Sure, I had some difficulty to understand the OP concerns and tried to bring an answer to the question in the title. One case of exceptions that must be caught is when a procedure or a request executes a "transaction", i.e. actions that must roll back in case of failure,. It is then necessary to catch all exceptions to return to initial state.